# How to run ffmpeg as apache user

Tags: linux

I installed ffmpeg on centos as root user. How can update permission so that apache (httpd) can run the ffmpeg command?

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 24M Mar  4 03:43 /root/bin/ffmpeg
```

I tried to link to /usr/bin

```
cd /usr/bin
ls -s /root/bin/ffmpeg
```

But when still not works. I guess because apache not have shell avaiable?

```
su apache -c whoami
This account is currently not available
```

Comment: Softlinks are subject to ACL of the file itself and all parent folders which lead to the file. I suppose your `/root/` folder is something like 0750. So instead of using a softlink, you could try an hardlink. Or move the binary to `/usr/local/bin` and all libs to `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: `/root/bin/ffmpeg` is kind of an odd place to have ffmpeg. Can you install it via a package manager? Also, as you noticed, apache does not have a login shell, but you specify one to run commands like this, `su -s /bin/bash apache -c whoami`.

Comment: Try to add user to www-data group: http://askubuntu.com/questions/97810/how-to-make-apache-run-as-current-user

Comment: Yes ffmpeg is installed on wrong place. It is a security risk. Recompile ffmpeg for shared users like this: `./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install`

Comment: @pub: Why is it a security risk to have a binary (not setuid) within /root? What would adding the current user to the www-data group change?

Answer (score -1):

As @pbu comment states, if you follow this installation guide http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Generic but replacing '$HOME' with '/usr/local', the apache (httpd) user will be able to execute it.

Comment: Why the downvote? A kind explanation could get readers/me some learning. Is the answer wrong? Doesn't answer the question or unuseful? Is it unpolite? Is it because '/usr/local' is not a safe place to install? Other reasons? Thank you